# Are there generalised rules for generating heuristics from data?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Heuristics seems to be more of an art than a science, like a gut-feel supported by data; I might be wrong. Are there algorithms for mathematically generating heuristics from data, like pruning a Bayesian network? Things like the Reichenbach Common Cause principle comes to mind. Is there a branch of mathematics that is specifically applicable here? Maybe a generalised way of expressing discrete data as a function in the way a Taylor series estimates a sine wave?

I'll do the reading I just need some pointers. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this what statistics is doing? If not can you elaborate why?

Comment: In a sense it is and that's why I've marked the question as statistical-inference but heuristics is more than understanding the data or even predicting where the next observation is going to be; it's a short-cut way of generating a new instance based on the observation of how previous slower but more accurate instances were created. Machine learning comes to mind but it's not a mental shortcut in the way a heuristic is. Abstraction is probably another option but doesn't quite explain how data is turned into a mental algorithm in a general way.

Comment: In some sense, this is equivalent to the problem of, "how do you come up with hypotheses in science". Suffice to say this is a big big question. As for specific algorithms, they will typically presuppose a bunch of heuristics - in statistical learning theory, a lot of the results are of the form "if you narrow your space of hypotheses to the following class of functions, then you can get a nice estimate". But the selection of the heuristics themselves, here, is somehow meta-mathematical.

Comment: I suspect that this might be related to the SAT-solver problem. When you think of the problem as "how do you generate heuristics for an NP-hard problem". The answer would be a partial SAT-solver (in the absence of a complete one).

Comment: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/gomes/pdf/2008_gomes_knowledge_satisfiability.pdf : "One of the most surprising aspects of the relatively recent practical progress of SAT solvers is that the best complete methods remain variants of a process introduced several decades ago: the DPLL procedure, which performs a backtrack search in the space of partial truth assignments. A key feature of DPLL is efficient pruning of the search space based on falsified clauses." Note the use of the word "pruning".